# IOS: map start with MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

In my app I want to open a viewcontroller where inside there is a map. In view did load I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    annotationPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self organizeMap];
    modalMap = TRUE;

    [map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];

    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"RemachineScriptPersonalUse" size:60]];
}
```

You can see that I want to start my app with a MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading but it don't work, it work fine only if I do it with an IBAction, this:

```
- (IBAction)changeVisualMap:(id)sender{
    if (!modalMap){
        modalMap = !modalMap;
        [map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
        [changeModalView_bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_bt_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [changeModalView_bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_bt_2.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    else{
        modalMap = !modalMap;
        map.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
        [changeModalView_bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_bt_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [changeModalView_bt setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_bt_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

}
```

why?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, it says `[map setUser...` but in changeVisualMap, it says `[mappa setUser...`.  Which is correct: `map` or `mappa`?

Comment: when I copy code I don't change fine names, but map and mappa are the same...sorry

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` might be too early. Try setting the tracking mode in `viewDidAppear` instead.